# Haskell Record function constraints

Tags: haskell

What is the way in Haskell to express something like:

```
data SinkBuilder
  { openSink :: MonadIO m => m Sink
  }

data Sink = Sink
  { writeSink :: MonadIO m => Value -> m ()
  , closeSink :: MonadIO m => m ()
  }
```

I guess what I need is a set of functions that are conveniently "bundled" together in a data type so this datatype is created and is passed around as one thing?

It seems useful for composition reasons, for example, I could implement something like

```
(:+:) :: SinkBuilder -> SinkBuilder -> SinkBuilder
a :+: b = SinkBuilder $ do
  sa <- openSink a
  sb <- openSink b
  return $ Sink (\v -> writeSink sa >> writeSink sb) (closeSink sa >> closeSink sb)
```

It doesn't work because I can't have constraints on record functions, but it also looks very ugly, so I am pretty sure there should be a much better way of doing it.

Comment: Isn't  `MonadIO m => m Sink` equivalent to `IO Sink`?

Comment: @Michael I think they are equivalent, if `m` is quantified universally.

Comment: Not really an equivalent, I have my own monad which is MonadIO.
Also I wanted to have more constraints, for example `(MonadIO m, MonadState MyState m) => ...`

Comment: @AlexeyRaga yes, but you won't be able to construct a `Sink` or `SinkBuilder` by wrapping things from your own monad, or am I confused? They can only be constructed by using `liftIO` and general monad operations, which is to say, they just replicate `IO`.

Comment: @Michael There is a difference between `IO` and an arbitrary monad stack built on top of `IO`.

Comment: Yes, but these rank-2 values can't be built with an arbitrary monad stack - only with `liftIO`, general monad operations ... and IO. I think there cannot really be an important difference between `SinkBuilder`  and (newtyped) `IO Sink` nor between `Sink` and `(Value -> IO (), IO ())` .

Comment: It seems you want `m` to be a parameter - `data Sink m = Sink (Value -> m ()) (m ())`. In this case you could have a function e.g. `Monad m => SinkBuilder m -> SinkBuilder m -> SinkBuilder m`. This allows you to add the constraints whenever you need them. What made you decide to have it universally quantified in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

This compiles, but I have no clear idea about what you really want to do. I fear that this is not what you want.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, RankNTypes #-}

import Control.Monad.Trans

type Value = Int

data SinkBuilder = SB
  { openSink :: forall m. MonadIO m => m Sink
  }

data Sink = Sink
  { writeSink :: forall m. MonadIO m => Value -> m ()
  , closeSink :: forall m. MonadIO m => m ()
  }

(#+#) :: SinkBuilder -> SinkBuilder -> SinkBuilder
a #+# b = SB $ do
  sa <- openSink a
  sb <- openSink b
  return $ Sink (\v -> writeSink sa v >> writeSink sb v) (closeSink sa >> closeSink sb)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this.
What I wanted is to have some notion of an effectful `Sink`: Something that can be opened, then I could send some values to it and the close it. 
For example, I could have a Sink that writes into an XML file, a Sink that writes to a Json file, etc. I also want to be able to compose them in a way `Sink + Sink = Sink` so when I send to the result sink both (or many) files are written.
The constraint here was introduced because some Sinks can be "stateful" in a way that they would require `MonadState S m =>` constraint.
I just don't know how to model it better...